# Migrate a report created with Makefile into a Maven site report

Tags: maven, maven-2, makefile, maven-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I am quite new to maven but asked to move my current report which is created by a Makefile in a subdirectory via `make all` into a `mvn site` report.

I put all my non-java stuff for my report into a `legacy-report` directory. So the current tree looks roughly like this:

```
pom.xml
legacy-report/
    Makefile
    www/           # <<< created by 'make all'
       index.html 
subtree-1/
    pom.xml
    src/
subtree-2/
    pom.xml
    src/
```

So my questions to enable `mvn site` for my legary-report are

- What maven (reporting) plugin should I use?
- How should I change the directory layout?
- How do I integrate that into the main `pom.xml`?
- Do I need a `pom.xml` in my `legacy-reporting` dir, what does it look like (roughly)?

Comment: What kind of report have you created via the Makefile?

Comment: @khmarbaise a single `index.html` with a summary displaying inline and linking to a lot of also generated PNGs and PDFs with details -- graphviz `dot` graphs to be precise (imagine it as a set of static call graphs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after clearing what you are really talking about you should take a look here for the plugin:

http://graphviz-maven-plugin.bryon.us/index.html

Which will give you the opportunity to create graphivz graphics via Maven. The question is if there is a way to create an index.html of it.